# How do I remove all specific characters at the end of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

How do I remove the last character only if it's a period?

```
$string = "something here.";
$output = 'something here';
```

Answer (score 175, accepted):

```
$output = rtrim($string, '.');
```

(Reference: [rtrim on PHP.net](http://php.net/rtrim))

Comment: It might be unwanted to remove ... (elipsis):

Comment: @OndrejIvanic: You have `…` for that. If you remove the last dot, and the remaining is still a dot, the question title wouldn't make much sense, would it?

Answer (score 35):

Using [rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) replaces all "." at the end, not just the last character:

```
$string = "something here..";
echo preg_replace("/\.$/", "", $string);
```

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wants to remove all '.' at the end, otherwise why remove just one? ;)

Comment: yes, i am guessing that too. just following the question as close as possible.

Comment: This is much better, too many people don't realize using `character_mask` in `trim` basically removes any instance of the character in the entire string

Comment: This will remove the dots too if the string ends with a newline sequence: `$string = "something here..\n";` because `$` matches at the position of this last newline too. To avoid that, add the D (Dollar End Only) modifier or change `$` to `\z` (z is lowercase).

Answer (score 8):

To remove the last character only if it's a period and not resorting to `preg_replace`, we can just treat the string as an array of characters and remove the final character if it is a dot.

```
if ($str[strlen($str) - 1] === '.')
  $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer since the other ones would delete all trailing characters not just the last one. But you should use `===` instead of `==` to also check for type equality

Answer (score 2):

Use:

`$string = "something here..........";`

[ltrim](http://php.net/ltrim) would remove leading dots. For example: `ltrim($string, ".")`

[rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim) `rtrim($string, ".")` would remove trailing dots.

[trim](http://php.net/trim) `trim($string, ".")` would remove trailing and leading dots.

You can also do this by regular expressions.

[preg_replace](http://php.net/preg-replace) would remove. It can be used to remove dot/dots at the end:

```
$regex = "/\.$/"; // To replace single dot at the end
$regex = "/\.+$/"; // To replace multiple dots at the end
preg_replace($regex, "", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

The last character can be removed in different ways. Here are some:

- `rtrim()`

  ```php
  $output = rtrim($string, '.');
  ```
- `Regular Expression`

  ```php
  preg_replace("/\.$/", "", $string);
  ```
- `substr()` / `mb_substr()`

  ```php
  echo mb_substr($string, 0, -1);

  echo substr(trim($string), 0, -1);
  ```
- `substr()` with `trim()`

  ```php
  echo substr(trim($string), 0, -1);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function of PHP which allows you to trim the data which exists in the last position.

For example:

```
$trim_variable = rtrim($any_string, '.');
```

It is the *simplest* and fastest way!

Answer (score 1):

The **chop()** function removes whitespaces or other predefined characters from the right end of a string

```
$string = "something here.";

$string = chop($string,".");

echo $string;
```

**Output**

something here

Comment: [chop() is an alias of rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php), and thus it is effectively covered by the previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the position of the last period character and remove it, leaving all other characters intact:

```
$string = "something here.";

$pos = strrpos($string, '.');
if($pos !== false) {
  $output = substr($string, 0, $pos);
} else {
  $output = $string;
}

var_dump($output);

// $output = 'something here';
```

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
<?php

    $columns = array('col1' => 'value1', 'col2' => '2', 'col3' => '3', 'col4' => 'value4');

    echo "Total no of elements: " . count($columns);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "----------------------------------------------<br />";

    $keys = "";
    $values = "";
    foreach($columns as $x => $x_value)
    {
      echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
      $keys = $keys . "'" . $x . "',";
      $values = $values . "'" . $x_value . "',";
      echo "<br>";
    }


    echo "----------------------Before------------------------<br />";

    echo $keys;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $values;
    echo "<br />";

    $keys   = rtrim($keys, ",");
    $values = rtrim($values, ",");
    echo "<br />";

    echo "-----------------------After-----------------------<br />";
    echo $keys;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $values;

?>
```

Output:

```
Total no of elements: 4
----------------------------------------------
Key=col1, Value=value1
Key=col2, Value=2
Key=col3, Value=3
Key=col4, Value=value4
----------------------Before------------------------
'col1','col2','col3','col4',
'value1','2','3','value4',

-----------------------After-----------------------
'col1','col2','col3','col4'
'value1','2','3','value4'
```

Comment: For this you just can use join(", ", $array)