# Regex - Trim character at the end of a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove a trailing `-` (dash) at the end of the string. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$str = 'SAVE $45! - Wed. Beach Co-ed 6s (Jul-Aug)';

echo ereg_replace('([^a-z0-9]+)','-',strtolower($str));

?>
```

produces this:

```
save-45-wed-beach-co-ed-6s-jul-aug-
```

How can I remove a specific trailing character only if its there, in this case the dash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might wanna check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103797/url-friendly-username-in-php/2103815#2103815

Comment: possible duplicate of [php remove last character if it's a period.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053830/php-remove-last-character-if-its-a-period)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [rtrim](http://pt.php.net/rtrim):

```
rtrim($str, "-")
```

If you insist on using regex, you can do

```
preg_replace('/-$/', '', $str)
```

The `$` character matches the end of the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution.

```
<?php

$string = 'SAVE $45! - Wed. Beach Co-ed 6s (Jul-Aug)';
$search = array('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '/[^a-z0-9]$/');
$replace = array('-', '');
echo preg_replace($search, $replace, strtolower($string));

?>
```

Output.

```
save-45-wed-beach-co-ed-6s-jul-aug
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is false because it removes every non-alphanumeric characters with a dash.

That should be

```
echo ereg_replace('-$','',strtolower($str));
```

$ means "end of string" and the second parameter is the replacement.
(At least I think so, I don't know the php ereg_replace function)