# how to remove a specified character from string?

Tags: php

I have a string like

```
a,b,c,d,e,
```

I would like to remove last ',' and get the remaining string back

**OUTPUT**

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

Another string like

```
a,b,,,
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a,b
```

Comment: what have tried so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - How to remove all specific characters at the end of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053830/php-how-to-remove-all-specific-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the `,` on the right side, you could use `rtrim`, if you need also the left side, `trim` is your choice. If there are also some `,` inside, you could split and merge the string again.

```
$data = join(',', array_filter(explode(',', $data)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
trim("a,b,,,", ",");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

```
echo rtrim('a,b,,,', ',');
```

Read [Manual](http://php.net/rtrim) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The `rtrim()` function removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string.

For more details [rtrim PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
rtrim("a,b,,,", ",");
```