# How to separate array by comma but don't want last comma

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want want to show an album's artists separated by comma and as a link. Artist's names are saved in array. 
Code will explain more.

```
    <?php
    $Artist_Name = array("artist1", "artist2","artist3");
    ?>
    <p class="style18"><b>Artists</b>: <span class="style24">
    <?php
    foreach ($Artist_Name as $_value) {
    $Value_new = str_replace(' ', '-', $_value);
    ?>
    <a href= "<?=BASE_PATH?>artist/<?=$Value_new?>"><?=$_value?></a>,
```

I'm getting the following result.

`artist1, artist2, artist3,`

I just want to kill that last comma and. Space. 
Thanks in advance.
Any help would be great :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - How to remove all specific characters at the end of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053830/php-how-to-remove-all-specific-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Use `implode(', ', $Artist_Name)` (see [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for details)

**Update**

For more complex cases an [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can be used for per-element processing:

```
$Artist_Name = array("artist1", "artist2","artist3");
$artist_links = array_map(
    function($value) {
        return '<a href="/' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>';
    },
    $Artist_Name
);
echo implode(', ', $artist_links);
```

Comment: I want different link for different artist. This will convert array in string.

Comment: This seems promising

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592994/remove-the-last-character-from-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053830/php-how-to-remove-all-specific-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string). However, there are a few ways to do it, for example:

```
$output = rtrim($string, ',');
```

EDIT: Having read the comment on this answer it's clear that you don't want to convert to a string. Therefore you can use a counter in your foreach and check when the last one is coming up. When it is, just don't add a `,`. Hopefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070244/how-to-determine-the-first-and-last-iteration-in-a-foreach-loop) helps

Comment: I don't want whole string as a link

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove last comma from a string, you can use code below

```
$lastCommaRemoved = rtrim($Value_new, ',');
```

**UPDATE**
Original code has many errors, here is fixed one

```
    <?php
$Artist_Name = array("artist1", "artist2","artist3");
?>
<p class="style18"><b>Artists</b>:
<?php
foreach ($Artist_Name as $_value) {
$Value_new = str_replace(' ', '-', $_value);
    echo '<span class="style24"><a href= "'.BASE_PATH.'artist/'.$Value_new.'">'.$_value.'</a></span>';
}
?>
```

I should also add, code below does nothing

```
$Value_new = str_replace(' ', '-', $_value);
```

Because there is no whitespace in values of $_value variable

Comment: But I'm using comma `</a>, ` here.

Comment: Assume that artist1 is `Justin Bieber` should be `Justin-Bieber` for a seo friendly link.

Comment: @Pradeep good point :) you are right, then code above should do the thing, did you try it?