# Can i remove some numbers with PHP that my code is getting from SOAP document?

Tags: php, soap

I have some PHP code that works perfect and it gets information through SOAP. I need to show my clients the prices of some products but instead of '€3,56' it gives '€3,560'. Is there a way that i can get rid of the last number? I can't change anything in the SOAP document so i can only fix it with PHP.

Comment: Do you want to always remove the last digit?  Only when that digit is 0?  Only when there are 3 digits after the comma?

Comment: Try this: [PHP - How to remove all specific characters at the end of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053830/php-how-to-remove-all-specific-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string)

Comment: Think I'd be starting by asking why the service you're using is giving you that if that's not the price. That or what you're telling us isn't the real picture.

Comment: @PatrickQ i always need to remove tha last digit.

Comment: @JoycePaesschezoone Then see Omer's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said `Is there a way that i can get rid of the last number?` so if you want to remove last one you can use `mb_substr` there is an example

```
<?php 


$a = "$3,560";
$b =mb_substr($a, 0, -1);
print_r($b);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slice off the '0' with a string method ( substr('string', 0, -1 ) or you could turn it to a number and use modular division ( num % 10 ).

For the first answer, the 0 is the starting index and the -1 is the length (counting backwards from the end because you wish to strip off the last character).