# preg_replace twitter url not working with question mark php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have created the next function to replace an url by a `div` with its id.

```
 function twitterIzer($string){
  $pattern = '~https?://twitter\.com/.*?/status/(\d+)~';

   $string = preg_replace($pattern, "<div class='tweet' id='tweet$1' tweetid='$1'></div>", $string);    

return $string;
  }
```

It works well when I use this type of url

```
 https://twitter.com/Minsa_Peru/status/1260658846143401984
```

but it retrieve an excedent `?s=20` when I use this url

```
https://twitter.com/Minsa_Peru/status/1262730246668922885?s=20
```

How can I remove this `?s=20` text, in order to make work my function ? Anything I know is I need to improve my regex pattern. thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove all specific characters at the end of a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053830/how-do-i-remove-all-specific-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: @HuyTrịnh, actually dont, because `?s=x` or `?m` the ending after the question mark is variable and its inside a preg_match,

Comment: @Sammitch I need to improve the regex only to remove everythin after the ?, including itself.

Comment: Parsing the URL into its component parts will simplify doing that.

Comment: @Sammitch could you please provide me an example? I just cant figure it out

Comment: `var_dump(parse_url($a_url));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just regex:

```
$pattern = '/https?:\/\/twitter\.com\/.*?\/status\/(\d+)(.*)?/';
```

Because ? is not a digit so it will seperate with `(.*)`, this mean every thing rest and in this case is `?s=xyz`, last question mark `?` is to say that is can exist or not.

[Learn regex](https://regexr.com/)